# How to find the keyword in a text considering the context?

Tags: python, json

I have a list of keywords that are stored in a json file called `vocations.json` and a database that contains more than 50000 records.

There are Wikipedia links for many records. And via connecting to Wikipedia, I am searching all the keywords for each record and trying to find if the keywords are passing in the first paragraph of the biographies of records.

The codes below are finding the keywords, however I need a more clever algorithm that the program will evaluate the keyword with the context of the text.

```py
import re
import json
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
    
    
def get_text(url):
    r = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
    div = BS(r.content, "html.parser").select_one(".mw-content-ltr")
    p = BS(str(div), "html.parser").find_all("p")
    try:
        return [i.text for i in p if i.text != "\n"][0]
    except IndexError:
        return


def find_occupations(url, keywords):
    text = get_text(url=url)
    if not text:
        return url, None
    occupations = []
    for keyword in keywords:
        for i in re.findall(f"\s{keyword.lower()}", text.lower()):
            if keyword not in occupations:
                occupations.append(keyword)
    return url, occupations


with open("vocations.json") as f:
    words = json.load(f)
```

For some records, the above code is finding the keywords correctly. Below you can see an example for the correct matching:

```py
url1 = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerolamo_Cardano"
print(find_occupations(url1, words))
```

The first paragraph of the above url is below:

> Gerolamo (also Girolamo[3] or Geronimo[4]) Cardano (Italian: [dʒeˈrɔlamo karˈdano]; French: Jérôme Cardan; Latin: Hieronymus Cardanus; 24 September 1501 – 21 September 1576) was an Italian `polymath`, whose interests and proficiencies ranged from being a `mathematician`, `physician`, `biologist`, `physicist`, `chemist`, `astrologer`, `astronomer`, `philosopher`, `writer`, and `gambler`.[5] He was one of the most influential mathematicians of the Renaissance, and was one of the key figures in the foundation of probability and the earliest introducer of the binomial coefficients and the binomial theorem in the Western world. He wrote more than 200 works on science.[6]

The output that I am getting is below:

```py
('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerolamo_Cardano', ['Astrologer', 'Astronomer', 'Biologist', 'Chemist', 'Gambler', 'Mathematician', 'Philosopher', 'Physician', 'Physicist', 'Polymath', 'Writer'])
```

But for some records as below, I am getting wrong results.

```py
url2 = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbara_Villiers"
print(find_occupations(url2, words))
```

The first paragraph of the above url is below:

> Barbara Palmer, 1st Duchess of Cleveland (27 November [O.S. 17 November] 1640[1] – 9 October 1709), more often known by her maiden name Barbara Villiers or her title of Countess of Castlemaine, was an English royal `mistress` of the Villiers family and perhaps the most notorious of the many mistresses of `King` Charles II of England, by whom she had five children, all of them acknowledged and subsequently ennobled. Barbara was the subject of many portraits, in particular by court `painter` Sir Peter Lely. In the Gilded Age, it was stylish to adorn an estate with her likeness.

Below you are seeing the output that I am getting which is not totally correct.

```py
('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbara_Villiers', ['King', 'Mistress', 'Painter'])
```

I know why the program is finding the keywords `"King"`, `"Painter"`, even though they are not the features of `Barbara Villiers`. Because these keywords too are stored in the json file and they too are passing in the first paragraph of Wikipedia page.

My first question is that, is there a way to find the keywords correctly via evaluating the context of the text? If so, what are your suggestions?

Second question is that, if we can search and find the word using a method that can evaluate the searched word with the context of the text, would it ultimately be necessary to review all 50000 records to see if the algorithm produced an accurate result?

**Edit:** Below you are seeing some items of `vocations.json` file.

```
[
    "Accessory designer",
    "Acoustical engineer",
    "Acrobat",
    "Actor",
    "Actress",
    "Advertising designer",
    "Aeronautical engineer",
    "Aerospace engineer",
    "Agricultural engineer",
    "Anesthesiologist",
    "Anesthesiologist Assistant",
    "Animator",
    "Anthropologist",
    "Applied engineer",
    "Arborist",
    "Archaeologist",
    "Archimime",
    "Architect",
    "Army officer",
    "Art administrator",
    "Artisan",
    [...]
]
```

Comment: Hmm, I wonder what `vocations.json` looks like and whether there is any contextual information in it? Maybe your [mre] should include a minimal example of that data - enough to test with and replicate your issue. And all of that stuff in your example about pulling data off the web, maybe the mre should just include some sample Wikipedia page first paragraphs.

Comment: Ok, I am editting my post now and will show some items of the `vocations.json` file. The answer of your question is "No". There's no contextual information in it, only keywords.

Comment: I edited my comment regarding also including some sample wiki paragraphs.

Comment: Ok, now I will edit my post too to show what the first paragraphs of the given links include.

Comment: Are you checking if a word from a list is occuring on a specific page?  Whats wrong with `Barbara_Villiers`? The re-directed page [Barbara_Palmer,_1st_Duchess_of_Cleveland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbara_Palmer,_1st_Duchess_of_Cleveland) contains all three words from your result: `'King', 'Mistress', 'Painter'`

Comment: I found the specific pages with a different algorithm. So I have the list of wikipedia pages also. Yes the link you shared contains the same text with the page I shared. And the code I wrote is finding `King`, `Mistress`and `Painter`. But I know why the algorithm I used is finding `King` and `Painter`, I explained this in the post. But what I want is that, I need a clever algorithm that could evalute the keyword with the context of the text.

Answer (score 1):

#### Question 1: Is there a way to find the keywords correctly via evaluating the context of the text? If so, what are your suggestions?

Keyword detection (also known as keyword extraction) falls under [natural language processing (NLP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing).

Some of the techniques for keyword extraction include:

- word collocations and co-occurrences
- TF-IDF (short for term frequency–inverse document frequency)
- RAKE (Rapid Automatic Keyword Extraction)
- Support Vector Machines (SVM)
- deep learning

#### Question 2: If we can search and find the word using a method that can evaluate the searched word with the context of the text, would it ultimately be necessary to review all 50,000 records to see if the algorithm produced an accurate result?

Developing a statistical model may not require training data, whereas, building a deep learning model may require significant data. So, it all depends on which approach is used.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking that I should use `NLTK`, I haven't read the documentation yet. And I don't know yet how to do what. Will `NLTK` help me with this? Or what other libraries I need to learn, can you tell me please?

Comment: Check out this article: [Python Libraries for Natural Language Processing](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-libraries-for-natural-language-processing-be0e5a35dd64)